# Explicit computation of the transfer in the representation ring for unitary groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homotopy-theory, lie-groups, kt.k-theory-and-homology, equivariant-homotopy

For a compact Lie group $G$ we let $R(G)$ be the ring of finite dimensional complex $G$-representations studied by Segal in http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1968__34__113_0.pdf.
This comes with extra structure, e.g., it has restriction homomorphisms $\textrm{res}^G_H \colon R(G) \rightarrow R(H)$ for every inclusion of closed subgroup $H\subset G$, transfers/inductions $\textrm{tr}^G_H\colon R(H) \rightarrow R(G)$ (Ch 2 of http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1968__34__113_0.pdf) and other structure maps which are not relevant for now. All of this can be summarised by saying that the association $G\mapsto R(G)$ is a global functor (see defn 4.2.2 "Global Homotopy Theory", Schwede S.).

I am interested in an explicit computation of $\textrm{tr}^{U(m)}_{U(k) \times U(m-k)}$ . It would be enough to know the image of the tautological $U(k)$-representation $\nu_k$ on which the $U(m-k)$ factor acts trivially.

My approach was the following:

Since the $\textrm{res}^{U(m)}_{T(m)}$ is injective on $R$ I wanted to compute $\textrm{res}^{U(m)}_{T(m)} \circ \textrm{tr}^{U(m)}_{U(k) \times U(m-k)}(\nu_k)$ via the double coset formula and then guess a $U(m)$-representation that has the same image via $\textrm{res}^{U(m)}_{T(m)}$.

Any suggestion, insight, comment or reference will be helpful.